# Basic question on Content Type Hubs

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type-hub, cross-site-publishing

Does a Content Type Hub require Cross-Site Publishing to be activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Content Type Hub is a site collection with the Content Type Syndication Hub feature activated.

When activated, content types created in that site collection can be published in all site collections in that environment (as long as the feature is activated). [Content Type Hub](https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000645828-Content-Type-Hub)

Check this as well: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Use-Content-Type-Hub-in-SharePoint-2013